# Separating nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am sure this is a simple fix, but cannot manage to work it out. I want to show a teaser only on a single node for my content type (e.g., node/1), and not all nodes within the content type. How would I do this?

Comment: But do you still want to show the other nodes or not?

Comment: Is this in the context of a view? Or do you not want the other nodes to be even capable of separating a teaser?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, depending on what you actually want.

1. A way would be to have two content types, one for node/1 and one for the other.
2. You could also solve this from node edit: when you edit the node/1, create a teaser and a full view, but for the others, create just a full view (no teaser). In this case, the other nodes will appear in full view even in lists of nodes.
3. You can alter the node view inside a hook_nodeapi (in Drupal 6) or hook_node_view (in Drupal 7) and force the full view of the node for any other nodes of a certain type, but not node/1.
4. Another way of doing this would be to also force the full view for the other nodes except node/1, but in a hook_preprocess function...

Maybe if you describe what you need in a more detailed context, then we can find other ways of doing this...

Vasi.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different displays of the view. On the first, make it a block, and set it to display only one item with the teaser. On the second, don't include a teaser and set the offset (under "items to display") to 1.

Make the first block display above the second display.